# Is it possible to use windows authentication in SQL Server database in 3-tier architecture with WebAPI service?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, impersonation

We currently have a two-tier enterprise application where a Windows desktop app connects directly to an SQL Server database. Data access permissions are set in the database using standard SQL Server features, sqlserver windows authentication is being used (users use their domain logins).

We would like to introduce an application server layer, but we need the same authentication scenario, i.e. all the queries, initiated by the desktop app, have to be run in the database under user domain account that started the app.

It is also important that users do not enter their credentials in the app, the current domain account is used.

Client application is a WPF .NET desktop app.

Is this possible using ASP.NET WebAPI as an application server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Active Directory to authenticate users, once they've successfully authenticated into your application, you will have their domain identity. You could then pass that as a part of the connection string for every user-specific database CRUD operation.

I would recommend that you have a shared SQL login though for core things such as caching, database logging and auditing, error logging, application authentication and authorization, etc.

Comment: Quick question about that related to auditing: if a shared SQL login is used, how the SQL auditing capture the user name who made the change?